# Oracle active/active architecture

Tags: oracle

I look for solutions that can synchronize data between two different geographical sites.
This solutions must synchronize data online or with minimum delay

What's the best solution for this architecture?
which existing solutions on the market?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Oracle's [offerings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/index.html)?

Updated according to your comment: It seems that you are looking for replication capabilities. In general this is a hard problem to solve. If you can limit the problem in some way, such as having central reference data replicated out, but independent satellite data capture, you may find things much easier.  Oracle have [offerings](http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora9i/ors.shtml) and there are third party vendors such as [this.](http://www.quest.com/shareplex-for-oracle/)

I've got no personal experience of these solutions. I suggest that you define in detail exactly what you need to do. Differentiate between infrequently changing data that can be maintained centrally and transactional data captured remotely. Specify how relaxed your consistency rules can be.

Comment: I look for solutions that can synchronize data between two different geographical sites.
This solutions must synchronize data online or with minimum delay